# Running different methods within an object depending on the 'type' of object

Tags: java, android, object, switch-statement

I'm trying to manage the power-ups in my game.

Lets say I have 7 'platforms' in my game and I want to randomly spawn a power-up with a max of 1 per platform (this is a vertically scrolling 'infinite' type game).

So, I have 5 different power-ups and I could do something like this (Where PowerUp is a valid class) - The '7' being passed into the constructor here is the number of sprites in the individual objects (ie, they are batches of sprites) - 7 so we can place one on each platform and just turn them on and off as required (I have a 'drawable' boolean array which allows me to do this for individual sprites in a batch).

```
PowerUP powerUp1 = new PowerUp(7);
PowerUP powerUp2 = new PowerUp(7);
PowerUP powerUp3 = new PowerUp(7);
PowerUP powerUp4 = new PowerUp(7);
PowerUP powerUp5 = new PowerUp(7);
```

I then simply add them to a list of objects to be drawn:

```
powerUpsList.add(powerUp1); //etc...
```

I can then do something like so:

```
(for int i = 0; i < powerUpsList.size();i++){

    if (powerUpsList.get(i).hasBeenCollected();
            powerUpsList.get(i).runPowerUp(); //Carry out the specific code for this powerup if it has been activated
}
```

The only issue I have with this is that I'm, in effect creating 35 sprites (5 batches of 7) - more when I add more powreups.  I will **only** ever use a maximum of 7 sprites at once.

Therefore, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
 powerUp = new PowerUp(7);
```

Then, when I spawn a powerup, after getting it's type randomly- (so, powerUp1 for example), instead of simply turning the relevant ones on within the relevant batch, I am changing the properties of the specific sprite within the batch.  So if the platform number at time of spawn is 7, I set the frame for the 7th sprite in the batch to the relevant one and then I want to run the code.

However, I seem to have to use a switch statement to switch on the objects enum before I can run the relevant logic.

```
switch (PowerUpType){

    case PowerUpType.powerup1: {logicForPowerUp1;break}
    case PowerUpType.powerup2: {logicForPowerUp2;break}

    //etc

}
```

Is there any way I can run the logic cleanly depending on the enum of the object using this batch of 7 sprites?  I can't seem to find a way to do this and using a switch, honestly, I find messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some monkeying around with the enum like so, assuming that logicForPowerUp1/logicForPowerUp2 etc are methods in the class which has the switch statement

```
public class PowerUpUser {
    private PowerUpType powerUpType;

    public PowerUpUser(PowerUpType powerUpType) {
        this.powerUpType = powerUpType;
    }

    public void usePowerUp() {
        // this replaces the switch statement
        powerUpType.execute(this);
    }

    private void logicForPowerUp1() {

    }

    private void logicForPowerUp2() {

    }

    private enum PowerUpType {
        PowerUp1 {
            @Override
            public void execute(PowerUpUser powerUpUser) {
                powerUpUser.logicForPowerUp1();
            }
        },
        PowerUp2 {
            @Override
            public void execute(PowerUpUser powerUpUser) {
                powerUpUser.logicForPowerUp2();
            }
        };

        public abstract void execute(PowerUpUser powerUpUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the powerups, then use a static factory to return them. Because of method overriding, you can do something like:

`abstract public class BasePowerUp {
  abstract public void calculatePowerUp();
  abstract public void performPowerUp(GameState state); 
  abstract public void handleFrameBuffer(FrameBuffer fb);
}
//arbitrary methods, fill in what you would do...
public PowerUp1 extends BasePowerUp {
  @Override public void calculatePowerUp() { /* ... */ } 
  // and so on
}`

Then wherever, perhaps in BasePowerUp have a method like:

`public static BasePowerUp getPowerUp(int which) {
  switch (which) {
    case 1: return new PowerUp1();
    //etc
  } 
}`

And if you set up the methods correctly, later whenever you call `calculatePowerUp()` the correct implementation will be invoked!